# Django Rest Framework: Count Number of Objects with multiple ManyToManyField values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

In the example below, I have two models with a ManyToMany relation and I'm trying to count the number of posts related to the tags.

---

There are 3 tags: Sports, Films, Health

There are 3 posts: 1 for Sports, 1 for Films and 1 post with two tags (Sports and Health)

---

I can get the count of posts for every tag as below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sports",
        "posts": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Films",
        "posts": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Health",
        "posts": 1
    }

]
```

My requirement is to count the objects separately for the combination of tags. So, the desirable output is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sports",
        "posts": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Films",
        "posts": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Sports & Health",
        "posts": 1
    }

]
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I combine the two tags and then count the number of post objects that have both these tags?

**models.py**

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    posts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'posts')

    def get_posts(self, obj):
        posts = obj.post_set.all().count()
        return posts


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Your codes looks correct. Are you sure you have 1 post record for sport tag?

Comment: Yes, I have made  3 posts. One is for Sports only and one other has two tags: Sports and Health. So it is counted as 2 for sports. What i want is to count it separately with combined category (Sports and Health)

Comment: it is possible to add multiple tags to a post. Which might be happened here

Comment: @ruddra: Yes, the default behavior is okay. I want the modification as described in the question which is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I managed to have a working solution by counting the number of objects for every tag in the API result on the frontend. It works for my case, as the data returned is not huge.

```js
let tagDict = {}
let data = response.data
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let key = data[i].name
      if ( key in tagDict ) { 
          tagDict[key] += 1
        } else {
          tagDict[key] = 1 
        }   
    }
```

Marking this as accepted until a better solution comes along.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding a related field in the Post model to the ManyToMany relation ease of calling the many to many relation from the tags side.

tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="posts_objects")

Instead of adding SerializerMethodField you can simply posts_objects.count in serializer:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts_objects = serializers.HiddenField()
    posts = serializers.IntegerField(source="posts_objects.count", read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'posts_objects', 'posts')
```

Answer (score 1):

use this in your serializers.py get_posts

`Post.objects.filter(tags__in=[obj]).count()`

instead of

`obj.post_set.all().count()`

Comment: This does not create a combined category of tags (Sports & Health). I am inclined to think that this task would be better suited on the frontend. I could return a list of posts with their tags from the backend and then count the posts based on the tag combinations in the frontend. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes you can do it, it is not bad way, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_counter(self, obj):
    counter=Post.objects.filter(tags=obj).count()
    return counter
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32544789)